# For Loop working but accusing error - VBA

Tags: vba, loops, for-loop, object, runtime

I have a little problem with the code below. In the bold line, it acuses "Runtime error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set". Interestingly everything works fine, but I don't want it to show this message every time. Do anybody know how to fix it? Thanks a lot

```
Private Sub applybutton_Click()
    
    variablesheet = "Cl" & box_id.Value
    maxrow = Sheets("Cl1").Range("A7").Value
    
    Dim i As Long  

    For i = 1 To maxrow
        If Sheets(variablesheet).Cells(i + 19, 1).Value = 0 Then
               flavorname = Sheets(variablesheet).Cells(i + 19, 2).Value
               **flavor_id = Sheets("products").Range("A:A").Find(flavorname).Offset(0,1).Value**
         Sheets(variablesheet).Cells(i + 19, 4).Value = Me.Controls(flavor_id).Value
        End If
    Next i
```

Comment: Probably the `.Find` is returning a null object.

Comment: Always specify the `What`, `LookIn`, and `LookAt` parameters when using `Find`.

Comment: You firstly must declare all variables. `flavor_id` should be a `Range` (object) and because of that it must be Set: `Set flavor_id = Sheets("products").Range("A:A").Find(flavorname).Offset(0,1).Value`. Then you must check if it returns a cell. According to the previous `Find` method used parameters, it may be return a range, or not... `If not flavor_id is Nothing then`, followed by the next code line and of course `End If`.

Answer (score 0):

To control the find nothing error, your code should be like (and in a more specific way, look in values and look at whole search text):

```
Private Sub applybutton_Click()
    
    variablesheet = "Cl" & "1" 'box_id.Value
    maxrow = Sheets("Cl1").Range("A7").Value
    
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To maxrow
        If Sheets(variablesheet).Cells(i + 19, 1).Value = 0 Then
               flavorname = Sheets(variablesheet).Cells(i + 19, 2).Value
               With Sheets("products").Range("A:A")
                    Set c = .Find(flavorname,  LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                    If Not c Is Nothing Then
                        flavor_id = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
                        Sheets(variablesheet).Cells(i + 19, 4).Value = Me.Controls(flavor_id).Value
                    End If
                End With
        End If
    Next i
```

Comment: Please note that you should also specify the `LookIn` and `LookAt` parameters of `Find`.